# Angular-cli gitpages deployment deleted my local project, and didn't deploy

Tags: angularjs, git, github

Per: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#deploying-the-app-via-github-pages

I ran this initially and it wouldn't work.  So I ran:
git add .
git commit -m "Initial deployment"

Then ran:
ng github-pages:deploy --user-page --message "Optional commit message"

It went through a number of steps, and I created the GitHub token and fed it the token. Then it asked for my username, and then it spit out:

```
Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git clean -f -d"
warning: failed to remove src/app
warning: failed to remove src/assets

There was a permissions error during git file operations, please close any project files/folders and try again.  You might also need to return to the master branch manually.
```

After that, poof, all files gone except for those folders. Also, nothing was uploaded to github.

Fortunately I didn't work a ton on this particular project, but curious as to what I did wrong.